# Not found yui-moodlesimple-min.css

Tags: php, css, yui, moodle

I have a little problem, I want to do accesible my webpage(with Moodle), I used http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and I have a lot of errors, the uri is on: theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple-min.css but I don't found it.

I look it the file(yui_combo.php) but I dont found anything, can anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this file is generated automatically from files:

```
--versionyui--/widget-base/assets/skins/sam/widget-base.css
--versionyui--/widget-stack/assets/skins/sam/widget-stack.css
--versionyui--/overlay/assets/skins/sam/overlay.css
--versionyui--/widget-modality/assets/skins/sam/widget-modality.css
--versionyui--/panel/assets/skins/sam/panel.css
```

At least in my case